# linear function which does not change the geometry of R^{n}

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

The linear function is given by $T(\mathbf{x}) = P\mathbf{x}$, where the transpose of $P$ is equal to the inverse of $P$.
For any two vectors $x$ and $y$ of $R^{n}$, how can I show that $|T(\mathbf{x})|=|\mathbf{x}|$ and $T(\mathbf{x})\cdot T(\mathbf{y})= \mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}$?

Comment: I started by expressing the norm of x, and I am stuck at the norm of T(x)

Comment: sorry about my bad editing...the /cdot means the dot product...

Comment: First, find out how the transpose is related to the inner product... $P\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = \mathbf x \cdot P^T \mathbf{y}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that for column vectors $x$ and $y$,

$$x\cdot y =  x^T y.$$

Also, since $|\mathbf{x}| \ge 0$ and $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{x} = |\mathbf{x}|^2$, the statement about norms is a corollary of the result about the dot product.

(I'll add that the matrix $P$ you are working with is called an [orthogonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)).